# Why would SQLite allow a table with nameless column?

Tags: sqlite

Looks like SQLite allows a table to be created with 1 nameless column. Any reason why?

Hi,

I recently discovered that I can create a table in SQLite where one of its column has no name. Like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS customer_data (
    ""             TEXT,
    "collect_date" TEXT,
    "first name"   TEXT,
    "last name"    TEXT,
    "last_visit"   TEXT
);
```

The first column is an empty string. And looks to me that SQLite actually allows this. I proceed to insert some data into this table:

```
INSERT INTO customer_data VALUES ('a', '2019-07-01 21:22:05', 'Joe', 'Johnson', '2019-06-22 14:33:01');
INSERT INTO customer_data VALUES ('d', '2019-07-01 21:22:05', 'Sam', 'Somelove', '2019-06-13 12:11:02');
INSERT INTO customer_data VALUES ('g', '2019-07-01 21:22:06', 'Bill', 'Bullock', '2019-06-24 10:23:07');
INSERT INTO customer_data VALUES ('j', '2019-07-01 21:22:08', 'Tim', 'Thomas', '2019-06-04 16:34:18');
```

SELECT 'em back:

`SELECT * FROM customer_data;`

Sure enough, here's the data:

```
<anonmymous>   collect_date .       first name  last name   last_visit
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
a              2019-07-01 21:22:05  Joe         Johnson     2019-06-22 14:33:01
d              2019-07-01 21:22:05  Sam         Somelove    2019-06-13 12:11:02
g              2019-07-01 21:22:06  Bill        Bullock     2019-06-24 10:23:07
j .            2019-07-01 21:22:08  Tim         Thomas      2019-06-04 16:34:18
```

My question is:
1. Why would SQLite an CREATE TABLE statement with a nameless column?
2. How would one access such column individually.

Comment: `select [] from customer_data` or `select "" from customer_data`. *Why would SQLite an CREATE TABLE statement with a nameless column?* maybe it's a bug?

Comment: It's definitely a bit odd, but `""` is saying you want a 0-length name...

Comment: Yes @forpas. It does seem a bug. Let me wait and see if there might be more insightful comments from the SO community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why would SQLite an CREATE TABLE statement with a nameless column?

I suspect that it's it's way of handling enclosed names in that they bypass syntax checking for invalid names.

- by enclosed a name that is enclosed in

  '' (single quotes),`` (grave accents),"" (double quotes) or [] (square brackets).

That is an enclosed name is not stored in the schema as the enclosed name but with the enclosing characters removed.

> How would one access such column individually.

You can use [], "" or `` to extract the column but not '' (treated as literal).

---

You can also have a table named as nothing.

Consider the following :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '';
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [] (
    ``  TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
    "collect_date" TEXT,
    "first name"   TEXT,
    "last name"    TEXT,
    "last_visit"   TEXT
);
INSERT INTO '' ('') VALUES('a value'),('another value');
SELECT "",[],`` FROM [];
SELECT * FROM pragma_table_info('');
SELECT * FROM pragma_table_info("");
-- SELECT * FROM pragma_table_info([]); /* does not work - no such column */
-- SELECT * FROM pragma_table_info(``); /* does not work - no such column */
SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND name = ''; 
SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND name = ""; 
-- SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND name = []; /* no such column */
-- SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND name = ``; /* no such column */
```

It results in :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ''
> OK
> Time: 0.205s


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [] (
    ``  TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
    "collect_date" TEXT,
    "first name"   TEXT,
    "last name"    TEXT,
    "last_visit"   TEXT
)
> OK
> Time: 0.132s


INSERT INTO '' ('') VALUES('a value'),('another value')
> Affected rows: 2
> Time: 0.143s


SELECT "",[],`` FROM []
> OK
> Time: 0s


SELECT * FROM pragma_table_info('')
> OK
> Time: 0.001s


SELECT * FROM pragma_table_info("")
> OK
> Time: 0s


-- SELECT * FROM pragma_table_info([]); /* does not work - no such column */
-- SELECT * FROM pragma_table_info(``); /* does not work - no such column */
SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND name = ''
> OK
> Time: 0.001s


SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND name = ""
> OK
> Time: 0s
```

And :-

#### From ``` SELECT "",[],`` FROM []; ``` :-

[image]

- Column name would be according to how the tool/language-coding handles column naming (i.e. they are given names)

#### From `SELECT * FROM pragma_table_info('');` and also `SELECT * FROM pragma_table_info("");`

[image]

#### FROM `SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND name = '';` and also `SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND name = "";`

[image]

Although it isn't explained  the following goes some way into explaining, perhaps why this anomaly comes about :-

> ### SQLite Keywords
>
> The SQL standard specifies a large number of keywords
>   which may not be used as the names of tables, indices, columns,
>   databases, user-defined functions, collations, virtual table modules,
>   or any other named object. The list of keywords is so long that few
>   people can remember them all. For most SQL code, your safest bet is to
>   never use any English language word as the name of a user-defined
>   object.
>
> If you want to use a keyword as a name, you need to quote it. There
>   are four ways of quoting keywords in SQLite:
>
> - 'keyword'       A keyword in single quotes is a string literal.
> - "keyword"       A keyword in double-quotes is an identifier.
> - [keyword]       A
>     keyword enclosed in square brackets is an identifier. This is not
>     standard SQL. This quoting mechanism is used by MS Access and SQL
>     Server and is included in SQLite for compatibility.
> - `keyword`       A
>     keyword enclosed in grave accents (ASCII code 96) is an identifier.
>     This is not standard SQL. This quoting mechanism is used by MySQL and
>     is included in SQLite for compatibility. For resilience when
>     confronted with historical SQL statements, SQLite will sometimes bend
>     the quoting rules above:
>
> If a keyword in single quotes (ex: 'key' or 'glob') is used in a
>   context where an identifier is allowed but where a string literal is
>   not allowed, then the token is understood to be an identifier instead
>   of a string literal.
>
> If a keyword in double quotes (ex: "key" or "glob") is used in a
>   context where it cannot be resolved to an identifier but where a
>   string literal is allowed, then the token is understood to be a string
>   literal instead of an identifier.
>
> Programmers are cautioned not to use the two exceptions described in
>   the previous bullets. We emphasize that they exist only so that old
>   and ill-formed SQL statements will run correctly. Future versions of
>   SQLite might raise errors instead of accepting the malformed
>   statements covered by the exceptions above.

https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html

Comment: Thanks @MikeT for your detailed response. You've provided very informative insight but yes, still doesn't quite answer why such anomaly should be permissible. I don't see how this is at all useful or practical. I'm considering submitting this as a bug to the good SQLite folks. What do you think?

Comment: @automike My thought is along the lines of why do anything as it would simply be bad practice to try to use no name, where a name is expected and there is a sort of disclaimer as per *Future versions of SQLite might raise errors instead of accepting the malformed statements covered by the exceptions above.*

Comment: I concur. Thanks @MikeT